# Failure to Re-open File after Closing

Tags: python, file, valueerror

I have been working with some code that is meant to print a poem. The goal of the code is to make borders that will fit the poem's size. But that does not pertain to my issue. I have been trying to get the code to reprint a file, line for line, but `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.` is all that is returned.

I've attempted to get around this by reopening the file after it's closed, and reopening it after the `def poemprint(poem):` function has completed. But both methods have failed. I don't know where to go from here.

```
import os
os.system("clear")

quitw=["no","n","ney","ne","nope","nuh-uh","nuh","noh","neigh","nye","negative","please no","no               please","quit","stop","q","s"]
harlem=open("harlem.txt","r")
hhop=open("hhop.txt","r")
poems={"1":harlem,"2":hhop}
poemname={"1":"harlem.txt","2":"hhop.txt"}

#10 lines of def quit() code

def poemprint(poem):
    print("╭"+"-"*60+"╮")
    print("|  Poem Printer [v0.5]"+" "*39+"|")
    print("⊢"+"-"*60+"⊣")
    print("|"+" "*60+"|")
    for a in poem: #line where error occurs
        b=57-len(a)
        print("|    "+a[0:len(a)-1]+(" "*b)+"|")
    print("|"+" "*60+"|")
    print("╰"+"-"*60+"╯")
    poem.close()
    if f=="harlem.txt": #doesn't work
        harlem=open("harlem.txt","r")
    elif f=="hhop.txt":
        hhop=open("hhop.txt","r")

c=(input("Enter a Poem: "))
if c not in quitw:
    while c not in quitw:
        while c.lower() in poems:
            os.system("clear")
            f=poemname[c]
            poemprint(poems[c])
            c=(input("Enter a Poem: "))
            if c in quitw:
                quit()
            else:
                continue
        os.system("clear")
        print("Invalid input.")
        c=(input("Enter a Poem: "))
else:
    quit()
```

Note: quit() is a defined function to stop the code entirely.

This is what I should be seeing after asking for the Harlem poem for the second time:

```
    ╭------------------------------------------------------------╮
    |  Poem Printer [v0.5]                                       |
    ⊢------------------------------------------------------------⊣
    |                                                            |
    |    Harlem by Langston Hughes                               |
    |                                                            |
    |      What happens to a dream deferred?                     |
    |                                                            |
    |        Does it dry up                                      |
    |        like a raisin in the sun?                           |
    |        Or fester like a sore—                              |
    |        And then run?                                       |
    |        Does it stink like rotten meat?                     |
    |        Or crust and sugar over—                            |
    |        like a syrupy sweet?                                |
    |                                                            |
    |        Maybe it just sags                                  |
    |        like a heavy load.                                  |
    |                                                            |
    |        Or does it explode?                                 |
    |                                                            |
    ╰------------------------------------------------------------╯
```

Instead, I'm getting:

```
    ╭------------------------------------------------------------╮
    |  Poem Printer [v0.5]                                       |
    ⊢------------------------------------------------------------⊣
    |                                                            |
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "main.py",line 44, in <module>
        poemsprint(poems[c])
      File "main.py",line 27, in poemprint
        for a in poem:
    ValueError: I/O operation of closed file.
```

Comment: It seems that you didn't include the call of the `poemprint` function. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help%5Cmcve) so I will be able to help you.

Comment: @OSA413 I've attempted to make a code that replicated the error, but I can't figure it out. It's simple this code that is producing this error.

Comment: you're closing the file handle in poemprint, but you're opening it from outside it. It only works once. The next call, the file is closed. make your function symmetric

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I closed and opened the file after ```poemprint(poems[c])``` but it's still returning the same error.

Comment: You have a bug, but this is bad practice. So just don't do this. open & close the file in the subprogram. If you have to read it more than once, make a list of the lines instead

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I got some help from someone else, and it's fairly easy to fix the bug without having to move the file into a life (which would take ages). Thanks for the suggestions though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your steps are:

1. You open a file in `harlem` variable
2. You call `poemprint` function with `harlem` argument. This `harlem` is *referenced* as `poem` inside of the function.
3. You close the file that `poem` references to (it is `harlem` outside of the function)
4. You **create** a new variable `harlem` that exists only inside of the function
5. After the function is done, you have `harlem` as a closed file

This happens because `harlem` in the `poemprint` and the one outside are different objects.

Short example:

```
def a():
    var = 2

var = 1
a()

print(var) #prints 1
```

You can read more about this in [mgilson's answer on a question that covers similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13881502/9245204) and in [the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).

### How to fix:

Instead of opening the files, keep their names.

```
poems={"1":"harlem.txt","2":"hhop.txt"}
```

Then modify the function to get the filename as the argument and to **open the file inside of the function**.

```
def poemprint(poem):
    print("╭"+"-"*60+"╮")
    print("|  Poem Printer [v0.5]"+" "*39+"|")
    print("⊢"+"-"*60+"⊣")
    print("|"+" "*60+"|")

    poem = open(poem, "r") #This
    for a in poem:
        b=57-len(a)
        print("|    "+a[0:len(a)-1]+(" "*b)+"|")
    print("|"+" "*60+"|")
    print("╰"+"-"*60+"╯")
    poem.close()
    #End of the function
```

Now it should work.

```
Enter a Poem: 1
╭------------------------------------------------------------╮
|  Poem Printer [v0.5]                                       |
⊢------------------------------------------------------------⊣
|                                                            |
|    Roses are red                                           |
|    Violets are blue                                        |
|                                                            |
╰------------------------------------------------------------╯
Enter a Poem: 1
╭------------------------------------------------------------╮
|  Poem Printer [v0.5]                                       |
⊢------------------------------------------------------------⊣
|                                                            |
|    Roses are red                                           |
|    Violets are blue                                        |
|                                                            |
╰------------------------------------------------------------╯
Enter a Poem:
```

Here's the full code:

```
import os
os.system("clear")

quitw=["no","n","ney","ne","nope","nuh-uh","nuh","noh","neigh","nye","negative","please no","no               please","quit","stop","q","s"]
poems={"1":"harlem.txt","2":"hhop.txt"}

#10 lines of def quit() code

def poemprint(poem):
    print("╭"+"-"*60+"╮")
    print("|  Poem Printer [v0.5]"+" "*39+"|")
    print("⊢"+"-"*60+"⊣")
    print("|"+" "*60+"|")

    poem = open(poem, "r") #This
    for a in poem:
        b=57-len(a)
        print("|    "+a[0:len(a)-1]+(" "*b)+"|")
    print("|"+" "*60+"|")
    print("╰"+"-"*60+"╯")
    poem.close()

c=(input("Enter a Poem: "))
if c not in quitw:
    while c not in quitw:
        while c.lower() in poems:
            os.system("clear")
            f=poems[c]
            poemprint(poems[c])
            c=(input("Enter a Poem: "))
            if c in quitw:
                quit()
            else:
                continue
        os.system("clear")
        print("Invalid input.")
        c=(input("Enter a Poem: "))
else:
    quit()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll apply the changes to my code immediately!

Comment: I've wrapped the code! You can find it at: https://repl.it/@KiKUP/Poem-Printer-v08