# Why is my global variable not working? (Python)

Tags: python, global-variables, text-based

I am making a text-based game for school, and I want it to have a personalized name feature, but whenever I get past the function where the variable is defined, the other functions only use the original value, which is 0. Here's an example:

```
global name = 0 #this part is at the top of the page, not actually just above the segment
def naming();
 print("A long, long time ago, there was a person who was born very ordinary, but would live to become very extraordinary.\n")
  time.sleep(2)
  while True:
    name=input("Who are you? Give me your name.\n")
    choice = input(f'You said your name was {name}, correct?\n')
    if choice in Yes:
      prologue();
    else:
      return

def prologue():
  print(f'Very well, {name}. You were born with a strange gift that nobody could comprehend, at the time. You were born with the Favor of the Gods.')
```

This is the exact code segment I have, and when I hit "run", It works fine until def prologue(): I have ruled out the possibility that it is something else, because in the replicator window it says "undefined name 'name'"

Comment: Given this snippet of code, `name` doesn't need to be global. Simply define `prologue` to take a *parameter* named `name`, and pass the user's input as an argument when you call `prologue`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Python what is a global statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881395/in-python-what-is-a-global-statement)

Comment: thanks chepner, but wdym parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a working example but isnt it better that you pass name to **prologue** function instead of using global variable? It is another subject but you have to avoid using global.

```
import time

name = 0 #this part is at the top of the page, not actually just above the segment
def naming():
    global name
    print("A long, long time ago, there was a person who was born very ordinary, but would live to become very extraordinary.\n")
    time.sleep(2)
    while True:
        name=input("Who are you? Give me your name.\n")
        choice = input(f'You said your name was {name}, correct?\n')
        if choice == "Yes":
          prologue()
        else:
          return

def prologue():
    global name
    print(f'Very well, {name}. You were born with a strange gift that nobody could comprehend, at the time. You were born with the Favor of the Gods.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    naming()
```

Comment: This did not work, no. It says 'name' is not a defined variable

Comment: so is that what you wanted? if so can you please select it as an answer and vote it up?

Comment: At this point I don't care anymore, nobody seems to understand

Comment: then you have to expand or refactor your question more understandable (:

Answer (score 0):

`global` is used *inside* a function to indicate that a name that would otherwise be treated as a local variable should be global instead.

```
def naming():
    global name

    ...

def prologue():
    print(f'Very well, {name}. ...')
```

As long as you don't call `prologue` before you call `name`, there is no need to initialize `name` in the global scope; the assignment inside `naming` is sufficient.

---

Also, you meant `choice in ["Yes"]` or, better yet,`choice == "Yes"`

Comment: for naming variable, how would I make a variable update so that it is the user's input for the rest of the code? And no, 'Yes' is the name of an input variable

Comment: What do you mean,"update"? Once you set the global `name`, it is available to the rest of your code (at least, the rest of the code sharing the same global namespace).

Comment: I mean that when I define it with user input, it reverts to 0 (default value) when I start a new function

Comment: It doesn't *need* a default value; get rid of that assignment. (It's not clear how that assignment could be executed again anyway.)

Comment: But when I assign it as a global and don't define it, it just has an error, and says "name" is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Remove global from name then it should work

Comment: It doesn't. I started with that, but when I start a new function, it reverts to 0