# How do I use the same variable in and out of functions?

Tags: python, function

I have this code:

```
num = 1
def function():
  num = num - 1
print (function())
```

Is there a way to use the variable num in and out of the function without it giving this error message:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'num' referenced before assignment
```

I'm a beginner coder, and if the solution is complicated and difficult just throw me a link to a page that teaches how. If it's not worth the trouble, say so.

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function

Comment: And: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881395/in-python-what-is-a-global-statement

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: But you shouldn't use `global` anyway. It makes debugging hard and reusing code even harder. Functions should get allt the data they need as parameters and give back a result with `return`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
num = 1
def function():
  global num
  num = num - 1
  return num
print (function())
```

You should add `return` if you want to see the result.

Comment: This answer is wrong. `nonlocal` doesn't apply to variables in the `global` scope.

Comment: @Craig, my mistake. Chage to global. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this StackOverflow question you will get an idea
[UnboundLocalError on local variable when reassigned after first use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/unboundlocalerror-on-local-variable-when-reassigned-after-first-use)